# How to GRANT privileges to user on Ubuntu MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, privileges

I logged in as `root` with

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

and created a database xxx with this command:

```
CREATE DATABASE xxx;
```

I want to give privileges to user webuser on xxx with this command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON xxx.*  TO 'webuser'@'localhost';
```

I'm getting this messages:

```
ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Additional information:

The user already exists. This:

> mysql> SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user WHERE User='webuser';

outputs as:

```
+---------+------+
| User    | Host |
+---------+------+
| webuser | %    |
+---------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: at first you should create webuser user to add the preivileges

Comment: @FarshadFahimi: The user already exists

Comment: the user not the `localhost` it's `%`

Comment: @FarshadFahimi: I don't know why it's %. In any case the  `GRANT command should be GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON xxx.* TO 'webuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` and that worked.

Comment: `%` means that every body can access

Answer (score 1):

it's better to use this link [create user and add privileges](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql)

or just before run this command 
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON xxx.*  TO 'webuser'@'localhost'`
 you should do this
`CREATE USER 'webuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'`
with this command you add the `webuser` in the mysql user on `localhost` with the `password` of 'password'
and after that add privileges to your user

Comment: The user already exists.

Comment: The correct GRANT command should be `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON xxx.*  TO 'webuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`